# checking if a matrix is diagonally dominant in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I know that my code is wrong because np.sum(abs(X),axis=1)) also sums the diagonal value, therefore my code will always return 'NOT diagonally dominant'. I have tried putting '-np.diag(X)' but i get an error message. Thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[ 40., 7.,   5.],
               [ 5., 90.,  7.],
               [20., 7., 50.]])


def dd(X):
    Sum_values_in_given_row = np.sum(abs(X),axis=1) 
    if np.all(((abs(np.diag(X)))) >= np.sum(abs(X),axis=1)):
        print 'matrix is diagonally dominant'
    else:
        print 'NOT diagonally dominant'
    return

dd(A)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To determine if a matrix is diagonally dominant, you have to check if the sum of the row coefficients **excluding** the diagonal coefficient is larger than the diagonal coefficient.  Obviously you take the absolute values as part of the test.  You are not doing this and you are including the diagonal coefficient instead.  As you mentioned, you should subtract this the summation of each element with the diagonal coefficient to ensure the check is correct, but you didn't put that in your code for some reason:

```
def dd(X):
    D = np.diag(np.abs(X)) # Find diagonal coefficients
    S = np.sum(np.abs(X), axis=1) - D # Find row sum without diagonal
    if np.all(D > S):
        print 'matrix is diagonally dominant'
    else:
        print 'NOT diagonally dominant'
    return
```

Note that the code takes advantage of broadcasting to facilitate subtracting the row sums with the corresponding diagonal coefficient.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful! :)

Answer (score 5):

The matrix **A** is diagonally dominant if |A<sub>ii</sub>| ≥ ∑<sub>j≠i</sub> |A<sub>ij</sub>|, or equivalently, 2|A<sub>ii</sub>| ≥ ∑<sub>j</sub> |A<sub>ij</sub>|.

```
def is_diagonally_dominant(x):
    abs_x = np.abs(x)
    return np.all( 2*np.diag(abs_x) >= np.sum(abs_x, axis=1) )
#                  ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
matrix = [[ 40., 7.,   5.],
               [ 5., 90.,  7.],
               [20., 7., 50.]]

def dd(mat):
        for numb, i in enumerate(mat):
                if mat[numb][numb]<sum(i)-mat[numb][numb]:
                        return False
        return True


print(dd(matrix))
```

Comment: Because it's not very NumPy-ish.